# No data found exception for SQLite Database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, exception

Hi i am coding in android and i was wondering if there exists an exception named `no data found`?

I know that there is such an exception in pl/sql, so that if I query a particular field/fields in that table and if that field is not there in that table, then this no data found exception will occur.

Is there an equivalent exists in android SQLite?

Thanks

Comment: Whats ur problem actually

Comment: do you mean "No such column"? or simply that the cursor row count is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no such exception in Android SQLiteDatabase.

If a query didn't match any data, an empty Cursor will be returned. You can tell a cursor is empty if e.g. `moveToFirst()` returns false (preferred) or `getCount()` returns 0 (less efficient but works).